# How I can retrieve and play audio file in cakephp

Tags: apache2, cakephp-2.0

I am uploading audio files using cakephp app. I can move file successfully to folder and can update its path in database too. But I can not retrive that file successfully. server reply with `206 Partial Content` AND some times with `304 Not Modified` status. can anyone help me to figure out why server respondig with such status?

Comment: Help solve what? All you've said in the question, is that you're able to access things with appropriate responses - i.e. there's no indication of a problem or how to reproduce it

Comment: server reply with `206 Partial Content` AND some times with `304 Not Modified` status. Is it what you want to ask???

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/cloud-computing/http-status-code-206-commad-line-test/ visit this link..

Comment: You've now updated the question but I think you've missed the point of my first comment: **there's nothing wrong with what you're describing** (it is _completely_ normal to receive 206 and 304 responses - that's how the web works). Please describe a specific problem.

Comment: I can not play file. when i write path to file i can access it. But It is not playing. showing status cancled, requested audio/mpeg file is not currently supported

Comment: Which web browser you are using?? Have you tried in cross-browsers?

Comment: I am using Chromium. I have tried in firefox too.

Answer (score 1):

You are using chromium. Mp3 is not supported in both chromium and firefox for ubuntu. You can convert `mp3` to `ogg` to play them in chromium and firefox. Or you can install chrome if you don't want to convert mp3 to ogg. If you want to convert them, you can do it with this shell script

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "The script convert mp3->ogg or ogg->mp3.";
echo "The script takes one parameter: ";
echo "[mp3ogg] - converting mp3->ogg";
echo "[oggmp3] - converting ogg->mp3";


if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo "";
    echo "Argument does not exist!!!";
    exit 102;
fi


if [ "$1" = "mp3ogg" ]; then
    for file in *.mp3; do
         avconv -i "$file" "`echo '../ogg/'${file%.mp3}.ogg`";
    done
    exit 0;
fi

if [ "$1" = "oggmp3" ]; then
    for file in *.ogg; do
         avconv -i "$file" -acodec libmp3lame "`echo ${file%.ogg}.mp3`";
    done
    exit 0;
fi


exit 104;
```

But you only problem is that chromium and firefox will not support mp3, they will support only ogg in ubuntu.

Comment: so, for every mp3's i have to run this script to conver them in ogg??

Comment: If you don't want to, you can tell your user's to use Chrome ;) it'll support mp3 format