# Cakephp read an audio file

Tags: cakephp, audio

I'm new in CakePhp and I wanted to create a view where I can read an audio file, here's my code from my play.ctp.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="files/niro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

I have also created an empty funtion in my controller.

The file "niro.mp3" is in app/webroot/files but I cannot read it from my view.

Comment: Here's the code:

Comment: <audio controls>
    <source src="niro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>

Comment: Hi, edit the question, do not put code in the comments.  And do some research, this is a duplicate of many threads here and others on the web.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19629469/how-i-can-retrieve-and-play-audio-file-in-cakephp

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but it doesn't answer my question.
I don't have a compatibility problem, I created a test.html on my Desktop with this code and it can read it.
Maybe it's a problem with the path, is it ok with "files/niro.mp3"? Or maybe I have to store the audio on another file?

Answer (score 0):

The `src` should be `'/files/niro.mp3'` rather than `'files/niro.mp3'` to make the path absolute.

```
<audio controls>
<source src="/files/niro.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
```

Comment: Yes it works, thank you for you help
Can I use the same thing with Html Helper?
I used this  <?php echo $this->Html->media('/files/niro.mp3'); ?> but it doesn't appear the lector in my view

Comment: Glad it helped. Please accept this as the correct answer so that it helps others who find this page in future. You should be able to use `media()` but you don't need to specify the `'files'` directory in this case as the helper already expects this. So you would want: `<?php echo $this->Html->media('niro.mp3'); ?>`. Hope that helps.